# When and why to map a lambda function to a list

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am working through a preparatory course for a Data Science bootcamp and it goes over the `lambda` keyword and `map` and `filter` functions fairly early on in the course. It gives you syntax and how to use it, but I am looking for why and when for context. Here is a sample of their  solutions:

```
def error_line_traces(x_values, y_values, m, b):
    return list(map(lambda x_value: error_line_trace(x_values, y_values, m, b, x_value), x_values))
```

I feel as if every time I go over their solutions to the labs I've turned a single `return` line solution into a multi-part function. Is this style or is it something that I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any situations where it makes sense to use a map of a lambda, since it's shorter and clearer to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead. And a list of a map of a lambda is even worse cause it could be a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension):

```
def error_line_traces(x_values, y_values, m, b):
    return [error_line_trace(x_values, y_values, m, b, x) for x in x_values]
```

Look how much shorter and clearer that is!

A filter of a lambda can also be rewritten as a comprehension. For example:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x>5, range(10)))
[x for x in range(10) if x>5]
```

---

That said, there are good uses for `lambda`, `map`, and `filter`, but usually not in combination. Even `list(map(...))` can be OK depending on the context, for example converting a list of strings to a list of integers:

```
[int(x) for x in list_of_strings]
list(map(int, list_of_strings))
```

These are about as clear and concise, so really the only thing to consider is whether people reading your code will be familiar with `map`, and whether you want to give a meaningful name to the elements of the iterable (here `x`, which, admittedly, is not a great example).

Once you get past the bootcamp, keep in mind that `map` and `filter` are [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) and do [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), so if you're only looping over them and not building a list, they're often preferable for performance reasons, though a generator will probably perform just as well.