# Using filter function to return full string if substring is part of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a `.txt` file and in it are random words.
I want to make a script that reads through the text and find any substrings, from a given list, and return the whole string the substring is part of.
Is this possible using the `filter` function?

What I have right now works without the `filter` function but using the filter functionality may make the script run faster. If it is possible, the `filter` would be the value of `results`.

e.g. I have a `.txt` that has the content of

```
Hello this is a test, redtreesarecool
```

Next, I have it search for any substrings that have the word `tree` in it. I want it to return `redtreesarecool` since `tree` is the substring of that string.

```
file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
try:
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as source_file:
        content = source_file.read().lower()
    results = [word for word in content.split() if any(sub in word for sub in search_strings)]

    if results:
        for result in results:
            print(file_path + ' | ' + result)
except OSError as e:
    print(file_path + ' | OSError', e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `filter` would probably not make the script significantly faster, but for what it's worth, here's what it would look like:

```
results = filter(lambda word: any(sub in word for sub in search_strings), content.split())
```

IMO, `filter(lambda)` [is ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945553/4518341) and should never be used. Instead, use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
results = (word for word in content.split() if any(sub in word for sub in search_strings))
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

However, since `results` is fully consumed in either case, it's simpler to use statements:

```
for word in content.split():
    if any(sub in word for sub in search_strings):
        print(result)
```

And you could move that into the `with` block and loop over lines, so that you don't have to read the whole file into memory:

```
with open(file_path) as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        for word in line.lower().split():
            if any(sub in word for sub in search_strings):
                print(word)
```

*That* will improve performance *and* it's easier to read.

Comment: Ty for showing how `filter` can be used AND why it's ugly and the better solution with valid reasoning. Really helpful. TY!!