# Create dictionary with lambda (incremental counter inside)

Tags: python

I'm newbie to python. I have this program:

```
wordlist = ['pea', 'rpai', 'rpai', 'schiai', 'pea', 'rpe', 'zoi', 'zoi', 'briai', 'rpe']
dictionary = {}
counter = 0
result = list(map(lambda x: dictionary[wordlist[x]] = dictionary.get(wordlist[x], counter +=1), wordlist))
print(result)
```

Result has to be:

```
result = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```

What I have to do is append all of the element in the list (as key) inside the dictionary with an incremental counter as value of the key. With this code I get "lambda cannot contain assignment. How can I do this? Thank you!

EDIT FOR EXPLANATION:

With the list of strings I have to create a dictionary with element of list of str as "argument" and value as "key"

The value is calculated like this:
The first element of the list is 0.
The following element, if it is a new string never appeared (unique) has last value (in this case 0) =+1.
Instead if the new element is a duplicate string (there is already one in the dictionary) it take the same originale value as the first.

The dictionary will be:

```
{'pea': 0, 'rpai': 1, 'rpai': 1, 'schiai': 2, 'pea': 0, 'rpe': 3, 
 'zoi': 4, 'zoi': 4, 'briai': 5,'rpe': 3}
```

And result instead with list will be:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Write a normal `for` loop and a normal function instead of using `map` and `lambda`.

Comment: Exercise with lambda and map, already done with for loop

Comment: I really didn't understand what the rule is for the final result

Comment: Edited! Sorry for my bad explanation, these are my first post. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: If it's relevant, I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945553/4518341) about why not to use `map(lambda)` and what to use instead.

Comment: I'm interested about it! @wjandrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Use dictionary's setdefault then.

```
wordlist = ["pea","rpai","rpai","schiai","pea","rpe", "zoi","zoi","briai","rpe"]
dic = {}
res = list(map(lambda x: dic.setdefault(x, len(dic)), wordlist))
print(res)
```

---

Dictonary can't have same keys. You just need a for loop:

```
wordlist = ["pea","rpai","rpai","schiai","pea","rpe", "zoi","zoi","briai","rpe"]
c = 0
dic = {}
res = []
for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    word = wordlist[i]
    if word in dic:
        res.append(dic[word])
    else:
        dic[word] = c
        res.append(c)
        c += 1

print(res)
```

Comment: Since `i` isn't used in the logic, you can simplify to `for word in wordlist`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest solution with vanilla Python is to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

wordlist = ["pea","rpai","rpai","schiai","pea","rpe", "zoi","zoi","briai","rpe"]
vocab = defaultdict(lambda: len(vocab))
# result will be [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
result = [vocab[word] for word in wordlist]
```

A more verbose equivalent, leading to the same result:

```
vocab = {}
result = []
for word in wordlist:
    if word not in vocab:
        vocab[word] = len(vocab)
    result.append(vocab[word])
```

Comment: Without import, is there a term to call a python code without any import? Thanks for your help

Comment: actually, @Frank's `.setdefault` version looks cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the dictionary built the code for the lambda will be as follows.

```py
list(map(lambda x: dictionary[x], wordlist))
```

This assumes you already have the keys and values of the dictionary populated. Is this the case, like so?

```py
{'pea': 0, 'rpai': 1, 'schiai': 2, 'rpe': 3, 'zoi': 4, 'briai': 5, 'rpei': 6}
```

Comment: It's much cleaner as a comprehension: `[dictionary[x] for x in wordlist]`

Comment: @wjandrea I know, but the OP has stated that the solution must use map and lambda

Comment: Sorry , I made a mistake with the request and the result is a little bit different, what i have to do, create a new post (and delete this) or append the edit? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make a dict with the first occurrence of each word, then look up each word in the dict. Don't use `map` and `lambda`, they'll only make it harder, or at least less readable.

```
first_occ = {}
counter = 0
for word in wordlist:
    if word not in first_occ:
        first_occ[word] = counter
        counter += 1

result = [first_occ[w] for w in wordlist]
print(result)  # -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```