# How to increase list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to get such a result `[2,4,5,6,7]`, how can do that? Now i get this: `[7]`

```
list1 = [1,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(list1)):
   l = []

   # list1[i] = list1[i] + 1

   s = list1[i] + 1
   l.append(s)
print(l)
```

Comment: See answer for best way to do this. Your method failed as you keep on setting `l =[]` for each iteration so you end up with a single element list with the last value of `s`. Put `l = []` just after `list1 = [1,3,4,5,6]` and it will work. Also you can simplify to  `for i in list1: ... s = i + 1`

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension

```
list1 = [1,3,4,5,6]
newlist = [x+1 for x in list1]
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a loop, you need to put `l = []` ahead of it - otherwise you're reintializing it as an empty list at each loop iteration,

```
list1 = [1,3,4,5,6]

l = []
for el in list1:
   l.append(el + 1)
print(l)
```

Notice that this code directly loops through elements of `list1`. This is a preferred way for lists and any other iterables. I recommend you use it whenever practical/possible.

As an alternative to list comprehensions and loops, you can also use a `map` with a `lambda`,

```
list1 = [1,3,4,5,6]

new_list = list(map(lambda x: x+1, list1))

print(new_list)
```

Note, however, that in most situations, including this one, list comprehension is a better choice. For reasons and details, look up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945503/when-and-why-to-map-a-lambda-function-to-a-list/61945553#61945553).

Comment: It's worth adding that there's no reason to use `list(map(lambda))` all together. It's shorter and clearer to use a list comprehension: `[x+1 for x in list1]`. I wrote [an answer about this](/a/61945553/4518341) with some more details.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you! I thought there may be some performance benefits, otherwise in a situation like this I myself would use a comprehension. Though I use maps for type conversions like in your example. I added the map solution as an alternative, for completeness.